# what does it mean to say a class cannot be reused? (specifically, Java FX 2 Task)

Tags: java, javafx-2

"a Task is a one-shot class and cannot be reused." [from javadocs for Java FX 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

what does it mean to say that a class cannot be reused? If I create an instance of it, surely I can use it again and again - as below?

```
    Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() { // task example in javadocs
         @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {
             int iterations;
             for (iterations = 0; iterations < 100000; iterations++) {
                 if (isCancelled()) {
                     break;
                 }
                 System.out.println("Iteration " + iterations);
             }
             return iterations;
         }
     };

for(int i=0; i<5; i++) { // reusing the task 5 times
       Thread th = new Thread(task);
         th.setDaemon(true);
         th.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly what you'd think. Instances of Task are only meant to be used once. This may be a limitation of the actual implementation, or a guarantee to you that code put in a task will only be called once. Even if it lets you ignore that stipulation, you probably shouldn't.

The document you linked indicates that you should use [Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) as a reusable Task-like object. It appears that a Service has a method createTask() that creates its task instances as needed. Perhaps someone with more Java FX 2 experience can expand on this.